# iCloud Drive / UIDocumentPicker confusions

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, uidocument, icloud-drive

I'm trying to add iCloud Drive functionality to my iPhone app, by providing 2 features:

- import a document which is stored on iCloud Drive to my local app
- export a document from local store to iCloud Drive

The first part is done, and it was pretty easy. I used `UIDocumentPicker` with `UIDocumentPickerModeImport` to obtain a file url, which I just read to use the document in my app.

The second part, however, kind of confuses me. If I understand it correctly, *all I have to do* is instantiate a `UIDocumentPicker` with the file url of some document from the app local store, and the `UIDocumentPicker` will do all the rest (= saving to iCloud Drive, in case the user picks a location there).

Is this correct? Because this is what I've implemented. And while the files show up **in the folder from picker selection**, they will not sync neither to my Mac nor to www.icloud.com. So it seems like they are somehow stored in "the document picker on my phone", whatever this means.

Am I doing something wrong? The file I copied to the iCloud Drive folder on my mac perfectly showed up in the import-picker on the iPhone.

Comment: Don't you have problems with .icloud (unsynchronized) files ? Unsync files are returned as .icloud files by UiDocumentPickerViewController didPickDocument at ...Don't know how to have the proper files

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the files *just turned up* in finder (and also www.icloud.com). So it must have been some sync issue, or it just takes a while for it to sync.

Question answered/closed :)